# "AttributeError: module has no attribute read()" but it exists inside a class

Tags: python

So this is how my project structure looks like:

```
par_utils/
  test/
    test_mip.py
    __init__.py
  utilities/
    MIP.py
    __init__.py
```

Inside of test_mip.py I import MIP like so:
`from ..utilities import MIP as MIP`

This is a peak of what my MIP.py file looks like:

```
class MIP:

    @classmethod
    def read(cls, fn):
        # Method implementation

    @classmethod
    def write(cls, fn):
        # Method implementation
```

for some reason whenever I call `MIP.read()` inside of test_mip.py it gives me `AttributeError: module 'par_utils.utilities.MIP' has no attribute 'read'`

I am not sure really how to proceed here. If i create a function globally and not inside my MIP class, and i call it inside test_mip , it has no issues.
So is the class the problem? I am sure i am importing it correctly. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `MIP as MIP` is redundant. I imagine you knew you had to write `MIP` twice like `from ..utilities.MIP import MIP` but just wrote the import wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You have a module called `MIP` and a class called `MIP`. You import the module and call a method that doesn't exist, because the method exists on the class. You can qualify it with the class.

```
MIP.MIP.read()
```

or you can import the class rather than the module.

```
from ..utilities.MIP import MIP
```

And as a general recommendation, you'll find problems like these occur less if you follow standard Python naming conventions. A module and a class should never share the same name, as the module should be called `mip` and the class should be called `MIP` (or `Mip` depending on who you ask).